# Need to show last time updated data on site

Tags: javascript

I need to shoe on my website date and time when is data last time updated. Does anybody know where to find  any good looking javascript  code for this ?

Comment: Where do you get the "last updated" information from in the first place?

Comment: You need an source for that information - the javascript is executed on the client (webbrowser) and does not know when the page was updated. Could you use PHP or other server-side scripts?

Comment: With out having data from a database how can you simply get it from JavaScript

Comment: for that you have to keep tracking your files when it would updates or store datetime in database. let me know if you want more.

Comment: One thing to add: everybody talks about database here - while that might be the best way if your content comes from an database, it is **not needed** if your content came from plain files. With PHP for example you could read the modified-timestamp of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you have to keep tracking your files when it would updates or store datetime in database. not other way to track.

Answer (score 2):

proof of concept

1. your `DB` table should have a column like this: `last_update TIMESTAMP(8),`
2. retrieve the last updated row with `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY last_update DESC LIMIT 1`
3. make an `AJAX` request usign `Javascript` ( maybe using jQuery) and display it,